# Selenium get(url) issue on Firefox

Tags: node.js, selenium, testing, mocha.js, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm having some issue opening going to an URL with Selenium + mocha. This is the line of code I'm using.

```
return driver.get('http://localhost/ClickSuscribe/#/MisProductos')
```

I've found that there are some issues with angular urls however I haven't found a solution.

The error is `Error: timeout of 40000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

This is the test case:

```
it("Is visible", function() {
        if(viable)
        {
            return driver.findElements(webdriver.By.id('activarMiSitio')).then(function(misProductos){
                misProductos[0].getAttribute("class").then(function(webElement){
                    if(webElement==='ng-hide')
                    {
                        console.log('Element not found');
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Element exists');
                    }
                }).then(function(){
                    driver.sleep(500);
                    //return driver.get('http://localhost/ClickSuscribe/#').catch(r => console.log(r));
                    return driver.get('http://localhost/ClickSuscribe/#/MisProductos').catch(r => console.log(r));
                });/*.then(function(){
                    driver.sleep(2000);
                    return driver.getCurrentUrl();
                }).then(function(currentUrl){
                    driver.sleep(1000);
                    console.log(currentUrl);
                });*/
            });
        }
        return console.log("No está loggeado");
    });
```

PS: this does work in Chrome and IE. It seems that selenium has issues handling URLs with anchor or pound, '#'.

Comment: is the problem about get method or script execution ?

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI I'm not really sure, but it seems that it is most likely to be with the get method because when it gets stuck there for about a minute then continues to the next test.

Answer (score 0):

The error says

> Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

You can inject the `done` callback as follows:

```
it("Is visible", function(done) {
  //...
});
```

And set the timeout of the done per test:

```
describe('...', function(){
  this.timeout(15000);

  it('...', function(done){
    this.timeout(15000);
    setTimeout(done, 15000);
  });
});
```

More info can be found [in the docs](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts)

There are also some [known issues](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2030), so I'd suggest upgrading your dependencies.

Comment: The first half of this answer is wrong. The error message is misleading. The OP is using promises, returning the promise is all that Mocha needs in order to wait for an asynchronous test. In particular, calling `done()` right after `driver.get(...)` is going to cause the test to complete before the `get` operation has completed.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the answer but it's probably not really helping any more now.

Comment: Correct as I understand with mocha you just have to return the promise.
Also I'm using
 `after(function(done) {
            driver.quit().then(done);
        });`